# ¿Que significa 2> en bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Me encontre con `2>` en varias lineas de codigo como esta:

```
cat miTexto.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Se que `>` redirecciona la salida a un archivo que literalmente la desechara, pero... ¿Para que `2>`?.
Tambien eh visto cosas como `&>` lo cual creo que ejecuta un comando en segundo plano y redirecciona la salida, pero no estoy seguro. Saquenme de dudas por fa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`>` a secas equivale a `1>`. El número delante del `>` es el descriptor que se está redirigiendo.

El descriptor 1 es `stdout` (salida estándar). El descriptor 2 es `stderr` (salida de error). Por defecto ambos descriptores están asociados a la terminal, pero gracias a estos operadores podemos redirigirlos a ficheros de forma independiente. Por ejemplo:

```
comando > fichero.txt
```

redirige la salida estándar a ese fichero, pero deja la salida de error aún visible por pantalla.

```
comando 2> errores.txt
```

redirigiria la salida de error a disco, pero dejaría visible en pantalla la salida estándar. También es posible:

```
comando > salida.txt 2> errores.txt
```

para enviar a ficheros diferentes cada uno de ellos.

Finalmente `&>` junta ambos descriptores y los redirige a un mismo fichero:

```
comando &> salida_y_errores.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

Se refiere a redireccionar el flujo de error estandar.

### Explicación extendida

En Unix y Linux tenemos un concepto llamado "flujo estandar" que es un flujo interconectado de datos de entrada y salida. Hay tres flujos estandar: entrada, salida, y de error. Sin embargo este último tiene su peculiaridad.

Antes que nada, en la historia se cuenta que esta idea de mandar el flujo de datos de un programa a otro fue idea de Douglas McIlroy, quien insistió a Ken Thompson para que implementara esta idea. Después de insistir (no creían necesaria implementarla), se revolucionó la manera de ver Unix.

Por otro lado, esta idea de *error estandar* surge porque los programas funcionaban de la forma input-output; pero esto acarreaba el **problema del semipredicado**, en el cual una subrutina que está diseñada para trabajar bien, de pronto lanza un error, y no hay manera de identificar este error de los datos válidos.

Está el famoso ejemplo de una división entre 0. Claramente nos va a dar error porque esa operación no está definida para los reales ¿Entonces como la manejamos? Podemos hacerlo devolviendo un cero cuando el denominador es cero; pero esto es mala idea, ya que también *cero* dividido entre cualquier número es cero; entonces tenemos dos conjuntos de salidas (uno de soluciones, y otro que provienen de inconsistencias) confundidos en la misma salida. Si queremos asignar cualquier otro número, caemos en lo mismo; ya que asignar cualquier número real también se confundiría porque la imagen de la función está en todos los reales, haciendo indiscernible la solución de lo producido mañosamente por una inconsistencia.

Por este motivo, a Denis Ritchie se le ocurrió solucionar este problema de una manera y fue creando un nuevo flujo de datos llamado "error estandar" (**standard error**, **stderr**). De esta manera, los programas conectados a la salida, sólo recibirían el resultado esperado, y el inesperado pertenecería a este otro flujo pero ahora siendo discernible.

Por otro lado, los descriptores de archivo son números naturales que funcionan como interfaces entre el usuario y un recurso. Estos descriptores de archivo están asociados con los standard streams, siendo convenido que el 0 se refiera al flujo de entrada (de lectura), el 1 al de salida (de escritura), y el 2 al de error (también para escritura).

Cada uno de estos descriptores de archivo pertenecen a una tabla de descriptores de archivo manejada por el kernel, y se asocian a una API que permite operaciones de lectura, escritura, cerrar, y demás.

Cada descriptor de archivo da una capa de abstracción sobre los recursos. Así que cuando quieres que un programa lea, se le asocia el 0; cuando quieres que escriba, el 1; cuando quieres que haga algo con el standar error, utilizas el 2.

En Bash tenemos varias formas de abrir un archivo "<" (lectura), ">" escritura, ">>" append. Cada una de estas operaciones abre un archivo en cierto modo (creat, open), devuelve un descriptor de archivo, y de esa manera permite que se manipulen los datos. Pasa algo semejante con las tuberías anónimas (el simbolo de pipe | ). Aquí Bash asume que "<" es para lectura, entonces presupone un "0<"; o que ">" es para redirigir el standard output "1>". Entonces, cuando manejas el número 2, estás haciendo uso de este flujo de error:

```
$ comando 2> archivo
$ comando > archivo 2>&1 # Aqui unimos el stderr con el stdout
```

Y por último, Bash permite referirte tanto a stderr como a stdout al mismo tiempo con el token &>:

```
$ comando &> archivo
```

Entonces, tanto error como salida estandar, irán a parar al archivo.

Un ejemplo gráfico es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde a un programa que sólo tiene un `sleep` y un `cat`, le redireccionamos sus flujos estandar de entrada, salida, y error, a cada archivo con sufijo respectivo al descriptor de archivo.

Para ver sus descriptores de archivo tan sólo usamos `lsof`.

Pero nota como hay tres descriptores de archivo pero, al menos ahí, dos tipos de llamadas al sistema: una para lectura "r" (asociada al 0), y otra para escritura "w" (asociadas al 1 y 2).

Comment: ¿Por que dices que cuando quiero leer se asocia el 0, si antes dijiste que el 0 es para la entrada?. Creo que cuando escribo sobre un archivo el SO esta recibiendo entradas de mi teclado, asi quede algo confundido.

Comment: Buena pregunta. Ya aclaré en mi respuesta. Cuando quieres que un proceso lea, se le asocia el 0. Cuando quieres que escriba al stdout, se le asocia el 1.

Comment: Cuando tu lees en tu pantalla, es porque el programa (digamos, bash), tiene asociada su salida al la pantalla, pero su entrada (su lectura) a tu teclado. Una cosa es que "tú" leas, y otra es que "el programa" lea.

Comment: En otras palabras cuando el usuario lee datos es por que el programa los escribe en `/dev/stdout` o en algun archivo especificando con `> [Archivo]` o `1> [Archivo]`, y cuando el usuario quiere escribir datos es por que el programa los lee a travez de `/dev/stdin` o de algun archivo especificando con `< [Archivo]`, ¿Estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: Algo así, pero yo no le llamaría "usuario", sino el programa. Es decir, cuando el programa quiere leer, manda una llamada al kernel buscando por el file descriptor 0 de otro programa o archivo (cat, ls, /hola.txt). Cuando el programa quiere escribir, manda una llamada al sistema a través del file descriptor 1. Así, 0's y 1's están encadenados. Pero ambas son interfaces que el kernel maneja para entender el flujo de datos.

Answer (score 0):

`>` redirige la salida standard (STDOUT) de un proceso a un fichero

`2>` redirige la salida de error (STDERR) de un proceso a un fichero.